# Question about MOC3052 and BTA12 usage schematic

Tags: triac

[image: Schema]

Hello ,

I would like to know your comments about Figure-1 and Figure-2 in this design, which I intend to use to drive a 3-Phase 1.5KVA Asynchronous motor.

In Figure-1, R2 and C1 are used to avoid unnecessary firing of the triac. However, since the price of C1 is high and the area it occupies on the card is high, I think to use the method in Figure-2.

Do you think the circuit in Figure-2 will replace the one in Figure-1 so that the triac does not fire unnecessarily?
If you say yes, I couldn't find a formula for calculating R5, can I ask for your help in determining it?

Finally, I am considering replacing the 10nf 1000VDC film type capacitor that I used in the snubber part with a smaller Multilayer type. I would be glad if you share your thoughts on this.

Snubber capacitor links

film type
https://tr.farnell.com/epcos/b32672l1223j189/cap-0-022uf-1-6kv-film-radial/dp/3519045

Multilayer type
https://tr.farnell.com/vishay/s103z43y5vn6tj5r/disc-capacitor-0-01uf-1kv-y5v/dp/3289418?st=10n

smd type
https://tr.farnell.com/multicomp/mc1206b103k102ct/cap-0-01-f-1-kv-10-x7r-1206/dp/2629504?st=10n